# Big Int in scala

Tags: scala, bigint

I'm new to Scala. I'm trying to create a test case for a simple factorial function.
I couldn't assign the result value in the assert statement. I'm getting
`Integer number is out of range even for type Long` error in IntelliJ.

```
  test("Factorial.factorial6") {

    assert(Factorial.factorial(25) == 15511210043330985984000000L)
  }
```

I also tried to assign the value to val, using the 'L' literal, again it shows the same
message.

`val b: BigInt = 15511210043330985984000000L`

I'm clearly missing some basic stuff about Scala, I would appreciate your help, to solve this

Comment: The [**scaladoc**](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/math/BigInt.html) is your friend.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The value you are giving is indeed larger than can be held in a `Long`, and that is the maximum size for a literal value in Scala. However you can initialise a `BigInt` using a `String` containing the value:

```
val b = BigInt("15511210043330985984000000")
```

and therefore

```
assert(Factorial.factorial(25) == BigInt("15511210043330985984000000"))
```